# Como formatar datetime em uma aplicação Flask?

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, flask

Como posso fazer para que mostre somente dd/mm/yy e tira as horas e segundos no meu banco de dados ou no templates?

<kbd>[image: imagem de exemplo]</kbd>

Banco de dados:

```
class User(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(120))
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(120))
    callsing = db.Column(db.String(10), unique=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(120))
    ifc = db.Column(db.String(64)) 
    password = db.Column(db.String(120))
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)  
    age = db.Column(db.String(5))
    grau = db.Column(db.String)
    about_me = db.Column(db.Text(140))
    last_seen = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
```

Template:

```html
{% for f in range(2) %}
    <tr>
       <td><img src="../static/img/arrow-gray.png" alt="">
           <font color="#006400">IFAB {{ form[f].callsing }} </font>
       </td>
       <td>{{ form[f].first_name  }} <b>{{ form[f].last_name }}</b></td>
       <td>{{ form[f].last_seen }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a função [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime):

```html
<td>{{ form[f].last_seen.strftime('%d/%m/%Y') }}</td>
```

Ou então, criar um filtro específico para isto.

```
app = ... # instância do Flask.

@app.app_template_filter('to_date')
def format_datetime(value):
    return value.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

E então usar no seu template como:

```html
<td>{{ form[f].last_seen|to_date }}</td>
```

Vale lembrar que nesse segundo caso é possível utilizar `<var>|to_date` com qualquer tipo de variável, então talvez seja interessante fazer um tratamento na função `format_datetime` para validar que o tipo do valor recebido como argumento seja `datetime` antes de tentar fazer a chamada da função [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime).